# Parallel plate voltage and repulsive force

Tags: electrostatics, pressure, coulombs-law

Imagine this,two square shaped plates with 1 cm2 surface area are facing each other,each is connected to high voltage power supply,the dielectric between them is air,the distance between is 1cm.

If we set each power supply to same voltage level and same polarity,how high will the voltage need to be so the repulsive force is 9.8 newtons,or pressure of 1 kg cm2?

Comment: Those aren't the correct units for force.

Comment: That's still a pressure, not a force.

Comment: Pressure is force per area, not just force. The two are not interchangeable.

Comment: You are right,I changed my question.